# NHibernate - Multiply price by 100 before saving

Tags: nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate with SQlite and I need to store prices. I prefer to multiply the price by 100 before storing it in order to remove the decimal place so that I can use INTEGER datatype instead of REAL, since REAL always uses 8 bytes whereas INTEGER may take 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes according to SQlite documentation.

Do I need to declare a custom type to take care of the multiplication by 100 (and division by 100 when retrieving the price) and use it in the mapping with `Map(p => p.PriceValue).CustomType<PriceWithoutDecimalPlace>();` ?
Or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

In NHibernate 5.2+ you may try to register your custom type as default for all `decimal` properties.
Something like:

```
//Somewhere before SessionFactory is created
TypeFactory.RegisterType(typeof(decimal), new PriceWithoutDecimalPlace(), new[] {"decimal"});
```